# Slack OAuth 2.0 without human (Add to Slack button)

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, slack-api, slack

Before I am able to get a token, Slack wants a user to give permissions to my request like described here:
[Slack OAuth 2.0](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth)

Is it possible to get a token without any human?

I would like to make my program posting modifications of another program to a special Slack channel. But if the user has give permissions everytime, he also could post the modification to slack himself and the Slack API is not useful anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not how it works. You only have to run through the OAuth process once (per Slack team) to receive the access token. The received access token remains valid and should be stored for future use.

If you want to use a Slack app and all the features it enables (e.g. Interactive buttons, Events API), you will have to run the OAuth process. However, if you only want to call a few API methods there is an alternative. You can get a so called "test token" for your Slack team which will also work and which you can get [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-test-tokens). However, this token is meant for testing and development and not supposed to be used in production level apps.

Comment: For the oauth.access method I need a code argument.
I receive the code via https://slack.com/oauth/authorize where a user has to choose a channel first.
The responsed code works one time.
When I try using the same code multiple times I get an error: code_already_used
But how could I get a code, without a human user?
Do I need a bot user for this? But how does this work?
There is not a lot documentation for bot users.

Comment: Yes, but you are missing the last step of the process. The "code" is not the access token. After you received the authorization code you need to exchange it for an access token by calling `oauth.access`. Its described under "Step 2 - Token Issuing"

Comment: I know, but the the token will not last forever, does it?

Comment: There does not seam to be any set time limit for access tokens, so yes in theory it will last forever.